# ArcGIS 10.2.1 Runtime Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

Whenever I attempt to run use run the Voronoi Map in the explore data option of the Geostatistical Analyst tool an error message as shown below pops up.

[image: Runtime Error]

When I run the debugger all the errors say is "Cannot find or open the PDB file".
I am not sure how to address this issue.  I have already tried renaming the normal template to OLDnormal for ArcCatalog and ArcMap and have reset my TEMP folder.  Has anyone else had any success in addressing this error?